# Unable to find Rajawali Video Texture in the latest revision

Tags: java, android, rajawali, rajawalivr

Unable to find VideoTexture class in the latest rajawali revision(1.0.295-SNAPSHOT).
Please let me know is there any alternate for video texture? or exact repository location or url with VideoTexture file?

Comment: You can use StreamingTexture for play video

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`StreamingTexture`](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/blob/master/rajawali/src/main/java/org/rajawali3d/materials/textures/StreamingTexture.java) instead like this:

```java
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_video);
StreamingTexture videoTexture = new StreamingTexture("video", mediaPlayer);
```

To update the texture image you have to call `StreamingTexture#update()`:

```java
@Override
protected void onRender(long elapsedRealTime, double deltaTime) {
    super.onRender(elapsedRealTime, deltaTime);

    if (videoTexture != null) {
        // update texture from video content
        videoTexture.update();
    }
}
```